# How does rate function calculate the result?

Tags: prometheus

I saw this question on rate
[Do I understand Prometheus's rate vs increase functions correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54494394/do-i-understand-prometheuss-rate-vs-increase-functions-correctly)

```
second   counter_value    increase calculated by hand(call it ICH from now)
1             1                    1
2             3                    2
3             6                    3
4             7                    1
5            10                    3
6            14                    4
7            17                    3
8            21                    4
9            25                    4
10           30                    5
```

I didn't understand the result of

```
rate(counter[2s]): will get the average from the increment in 2 sec and distribute it among the seconds
So in the first 2 second we got an increment of total 3 which means the average is 1.5/sec. final result:

second result
1       1,5
2       1,5
3        2
4        2
5       3,5
6       3,5
7       3,5
8       3,5
9       4,5
10      4,5
```

and

```
rate(counter[5s]): will get the average from the increment in 5 sec and distribute it among the seconds
The same as for [2s] but we calculate the average from total increment of 5sec. final result:

second result
1        2
2        2
3        2
4        2
5        2
6        4
7        4
8        4
9        4
```

Could you explain me please the logic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that OP in the question has simply calculated it incorrectly. The [only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54497684/9274948) to that question explains it very clearly and into detail, providing the exact formula to use. Also with an example (in comments):

> if `t1` is 1 and `t5` is 5; and the value at `t1` is 1 and the value at `t5` is 10 (as above) then `(v5 - v1) / (t5 - t1)` is `(10 - 1) / (5 - 1)`, i.e. `2.25`

Which clearly contradicts the `rate(counter[5s])` from the original example at 5th second which says 2. Also note that in the answer says the ICH for sec 1 should be 0.

I will now try to calculate it by hand:

```
rate(counter[5s]): (v_y - v_x) / (t_y - t_x)

second result     calculation
1       N/A     (1 - 1) / (1 - 1)
2        2      (3 - 1) / (2 - 1)
3       2.5     (6 - 1) / (3 - 1)
4        2      (7 - 1) / (4 - 1)
5       2.25    (10 - 1) / (5 - 1)
6       2.75    (14 - 3) / (6 - 2)
7       2.75    (17 - 6) / (7 - 3)
8       3.5     (21 - 7) / (8 - 4)
9       3.75    (25 - 10) / (9 - 5)
10      4       (30 - 14) / (10 - 6)
```