# Prometheus Error Rate alert : interval range question

Tags: prometheus, alert, promql

I am very new to Prometheus and have the following alert in Prometheus whose goal is to get triggered when number errors in the total number of requests is higher than 5 %:

```
sum(increase(errorMetric{service_name="someservice"}[5m])) /  sum(increase(http_requests_count{service_name="someservice", path="/some/path"}[5m])) > 0.05
```

I have an overall idea of the traffic and it can range between 100 requests per hour over 24h interval. How valuable is to have the interval set for 5m? Shall this range over a longer period of time, e.g. 1h. This alert goes off and it does not really inform us of a problem. What is your view?

Thank you

Comment: Additional question: is there a strong reason as why I should use ```rate``` as opposed to ```increase```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buried in the mass Prometheus docs, there is a paragraph for `increase` function:

> `increase` should only be used with counters and native histograms where the components behave like counters. It is **syntactic sugar** for `rate(v)` multiplied by the number of seconds under the specified time range window, and *should be used primarily for human readability*.

So answer your questions:

1. Is there a strong reason as why I should use `rate` as opposed to `increase`?

   Yes, use the `rate` function.
2. How valuable is to have the interval set for 5m?

   Not so valuable. Since your RPS/QPS is very small - less than 10 per 5m, you may get some 5m time ranges with little or zero requests and others with much more requests. The alert rule will be too sensitive or just wrong in a wider time range view. 30m or 1h range might be better.

By the way, time series on each side of `division` operator should have matching labels to make the alert rule work.

Comment: Thanks, I always find that except from the Prometheus a bit vague for my own understanding. ```increase should only be used with counters and native histograms where the components behave like counters```. What are the cases in which counters do not behave like counters, then? This is where I am confused. In my case, that is a counter and indeed behaves as one, but I am not sure I am aware of a situation in which that does not apply. Can you help?

Comment: In that respect, I think this question is a great explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54494394/do-i-understand-prometheuss-rate-vs-increase-functions-correctly

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have e.g. slow-changing integer counter, which may increase by less than 100 during an hour. Prometheus can return unexpected results from `increase()` function when applied to slow-changing integer counters because of the following issues:

- `increase(m[d])` may return fractional results over integer counter `m` because of extrapolation. See [this issue](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3746).
- `increase(m[d])` may miss counter increase between the last raw sample just before the lookbehind window `d` and the first raw sample inside the lookbehind window `d`. See [this article](https://medium.com/@romanhavronenko/victoriametrics-promql-compliance-d4318203f51e) for more details.
- `increase(m[d])` may miss the initial counter increase if `m` time series starts from value other than zero.

The same issues are applied to `rate()` as well, since `increase()` is a syntactic sugar over `rate()` in Prometheus, e.g. `increase(m[d]) = rate(m[d]) * d`.

It is recommended using longer lookbehind windows for `rate()` and `increase()` functions when they are applied to slow-changing counters, in order to minimize the significance of issues mentioned above. For example, to use `1h` lookbehind window in square brackets instead of `5m`, so the increased window catches non-zero counter increases.

As for the original query, it is better rewriting it to the following one:

```
(
  sum(increase(errorMetric{service_name="someservice"}[1h]))
    /
  sum(increase(http_requests_count{service_name="someservice"}[1h]))
) > 0.05
```

This query contains the following changes comparing to the original query:

- `5m` lookbehind window has been changed to `1h`
- the `path` label filter has been removed from the `http_requests_count` metric selector, so the number of `errorMetric` time series matches the number of `http_requests_count` time series. On the other hand, the `path` label filter could be added to `errorMetric` metric selector instead.